# In Aegir panel (during verify platform hostmaster) “sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified” - warning

Tags: aegir

[image]I have managed to enter in the aegir panel and change the password.
I have noticed that the platform hostmaster verify has an alert:

**“ sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified”** - warning

I did some research In this forum and I tried to modify the file /etc/sudoers.tmp but it didn’t work.
I have also tried many solutions proposed in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error
but they didn't work.

Any other idea how to fix this?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: If it's not causing any problems, you can ignore it.  Looks like you already found the issue at https://www.drupal.org/project/provision/issues/2842473 .

Comment: Thank you! yes I believe i will disable the 2 modules to "fix permission". They really don't help.

Comment: @colan
 I am not able to access to phpmyadmin that is in the folder "hostmaster-7.x-3.192".  it should be accessible through "http://panel.example.org/phpmyadmin/". At least in a previous installation it worked like that. Now I this new installation I am having the issue of "no tty present and no askpass program specified" and I guess that can be related to the access to that folder. 

where do you usually put the folder phpmyadmin ? (inside aegir I mean)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help with that as I don't use it.  I just access the DB from the CLI by running `drush @site sql-connect`.

Comment: Thank you Colan! I will try that too